# OrmLite pattern for static methods in business logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, ormlite-servicestack

For a Web-based (ASP.NET) environment, what would be the best way to design the base service class using OrmLite (for factory and connection), such that the business logic classes (derived from the base class) can support static methods for database operations?

Sample business logic class:

```cs
public class Jobs : Service
{
    public static Job Get(int JobId)
    {
        return db.Id<Job>(JobId);
    }
}
```

I basically want to reduce code repetition (for OrmLite factory and connection handling) and support static methods. I'm not sure if making the `IDbConnectionFactory` and `IDbConnection` objects as static in the base `Service` class will be sufficient. I've looked at a similar question ([ServiceStack + ORMLite + Repository Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480237/servicestack-ormlite-repository-pattern)) but it addresses the issue with non-static methods.